# Why am I timing out when using the Menu Editor?

Tags: admin, menus, admin-menu

I'm using a more or less fresh local install of WP 3.3.1. A few days ago I set up a couple menus (Appearance > Menus) without a hitch. Today I tried creating a new menu and add a page to it, but the page was never successfully added to the menu; the spinner just went on forever.

I thought maybe the menu name was conflicting with one I had deleted earlier, but I can no longer add pages to new or existing menus. The same goes for custom links; I just get the spinner even after waiting 15 minutes.

I only have one plugin enabled, Advanced Custom Fields 3.0.6, which I disabled to no avail. I have no custom post types or taxonomies. There are about 15 pages total with very little content on them, so WP isn't getting stuck sifting through a bunch of data. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I looked through the error log in MAMP and discovered a bunch of weird garbage. After Googling some pertinent strings (i.e. "caught SIGTERM, shutting down"), the best advice I got was to reinstall PHP with MAMP; now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with custom menu's there can not be any conflicts because, If I'm not mistaking, menu that has a name of a deleted one, will be assigned a new ID and/or a slug so it would be different from the old one. The only thing I can think of is that there is a problem with your server or MySQL which either is very slow or just not working. Also, did you try a different browser? A long shot, but nevertheless worth a try.

Comment: Switching browsers didn't work. I'll try a DB optimizer plugin to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Keep in mind that if wordpress itself runs fast and other functions work perfectly, the problem most likely is not in the database nor the server.

Comment: I have multiple Wordpress installs on my local server and the menu editor is working perfectly in them; this leads me to believe that it's something specific to this install of WP.

Comment: That might be. There are a ton of people with problems not on local servers, but on public servers which are usually caused by either broken installation or a faulty server.